# Perl documentation using sphinx

Tags: perl, python-sphinx

How do I use sphinx, which is great for auto documenting python code, to document perl code ?

Comment: Why this question was downvoted? (+1) Sphinx is great for almost any (doc) task. I had same question with PHP ;) ... Results: In general speak you'll have to create a 'plugin' for sphinx (think to remember its called a domain file) and then write (or use ) code that creates files in the syntax of the domain file from your perl code..

Answer (score 3):

Perl code should be documented with [POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html), this is the natural way, and supported in this environment. It's easy and powerful.

Comment: You have to take into account that Perl might be a part of a larger system, where other languages are represented. So consolidating documentation can be of interest to the organisation developing and operating the system. Dist::Zilla can generate Markdown, for other POD files I use pod2markdown. This is more easily consumable for some of the tools and products used in our toolchain, which do not handle POD natively.

Answer (score 0):

try [Documenting Your Project Using Sphinx](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html)

Or

A video on [You Tube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ6pFgQXQ0Q)

Comment: The question is about documenting Perl code with Sphinx. This answer does not address that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx is very Python specific AFAIK, however somebody are working on implementing a Javascript integration: https://github.com/erikrose/sphinx-js - meaning that it could be doable for Perl, but it will possibly not be easy.

Perhaps Perl's subroutine signatures could be interesting to evaluate, take a look at brian d foy's blog post: https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/04/use-v5-20-subroutine-signatures/